# Shiro in Java EE 6 application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, shiro

I was following BalusC code to manage user authentication in Java EE 6 (http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html) which works great if I stay on the same web container.

I'm facing an issue that perhaps anyone can help me.
When injecting an EJB that resides in the Web container, the `SecurityUtils.getSubject()` works ok from any method of that EJB.

The problem is when I try to do it on an injected EJB from another container (even an ejb jar in the same EAR).

The error I get is:

> Caused by: org.apache.shiro.UnavailableSecurityManagerException: No SecurityManager accessible to the calling code, either bound to the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static singleton.  This is an invalid application configuration.

The use case is:

Managed bean `A` with injected stateless session bean `B`. Class `A` resides in myApp.war, class `B` resides in myApp.ejb, both inside myApp.ear. I am calling `SecurityUtils` from class `B`.

Do you have any clues on how to solve this?

I am running JSF 2, Java EE 6, JBoss 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering the question myself.

I solved the integration using a Filter and a custom LoginModule for JBoss:

The filter (it must be applied after the invocation of shiro filter):

```
public class ShiroJAASIntegrationFilter implements Filter{

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ShiroJAASIntegrationFilter.class);
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1,
            FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)arg0;
        Principal userPrincipal = httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal();
        HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
        if(userPrincipal!=null){
            if(session!= null && session.getAttribute("shiroAuthenticated")==null){
                String name = userPrincipal.getName();
                try {
                    httpServletRequest.login(name,"");
                    session.setAttribute("shiroAuthenticated",true);
                } catch (ServletException e) {
                    logger.debug("Unable to authenticate user" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }
        arg2.doFilter(arg0, arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

The loginmodule, it just sets the user as authenticated:

```
public class ShiroJAASLoginModule extends UsernamePasswordLoginModule {

    /**
     * Always return true. 
     */
    protected boolean validatePassword(String inputPassword,
            String expectedPassword) {
        return true;
    }

    protected Group[] getRoleSets() throws LoginException {
        //TODO: if needed, add roles
        Group[] roleSets = { new SimpleGroup("Roles") };
        roleSets[0].addMember(new SimplePrincipal(getUsername()));
        return roleSets;
    }


    @Override
    protected String getUsersPassword() throws LoginException {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The module must be defined in standalone.xml:

```
<security-domain name="shiro" cache-type="default">
 <authentication>
  <login-module code="web.security.shiroJaasIntegration.ShiroJAASLoginModule" flag="required"/>
 </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Finally,define the security-domain in your apps jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>shiro</security-domain>

</jboss-web>
```

Comment: I'm facing the same exception. Do you remember what specifically caused the problem and how this code solves it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Shiro bind `SecurityManager` as `ThreadLocal` via `ShiroFilter`. Look at the `doFilterInternal` method. The `Subject` is bind to `ThreadContext` **only inside** `subject.execute` method, which means the `SecurityUtils.getSubject()` will return null each time it will be called outside subject.execute, which means outside ShiroFilter, which means **outside request thread** and this is the problem i think.

**AbstractShiroFilter.java**

```
protected void doFilterInternal(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, final FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
...

            final Subject subject = createSubject(request, response);

            //noinspection unchecked
            subject.execute(new Callable() {
                public Object call() throws Exception {
                    updateSessionLastAccessTime(request, response);
                    executeChain(request, response, chain);
                    return null;
                }
            });    
...
    }
```

Well, you said you `inject Stateless B` whats your DI framework? Shiro can integrate with Guice and Spring quite easily.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your input. I use EJB3.1 with JSF2 and cannot switch to Guice nor Spring at the moment.

Actually the ejb is called in the same thread of the shirofilter, I don't know why when it comes to the stack of the EJB3.1 project, the Shiro ThreadLocal disappears.. Perhaps I can add it manually using a second filter, but maybe it's a problem with the EJB stack.