# Guice @SessionScoped annotation causes IllegalArgumentException with Shiro HttpSession

Tags: java, guice, shiro, java-ee-5, wicket-1.5

I have an Apache Wicket 1.5 application that uses Shiro for security, and Guice for dependency injection.
Most of its pages are stateless, but some of my model objects (user data, current menu state, ...) need to be consistent across all requests in the same session. All of these objects have both logic (mostly simple finder methods using remote EJB3 interfaces to access a database) and state, and all of them implement Serializable.

Here's a short excerpt that should convey the idea:

```
@SessionScoped
public class UsersImpl implements Users, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8841809043461673585L;
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( UsersImpl.class );

    @Inject
    public UserService users;

    @Inject
    public RoleService roles;

    private UserDTO currentUser;

    public UserVO findUserByUser( UserVO user ) {
        UserDTO userDto = null;
        try {
            userDto = users.findUserByUser( user.toUserDTO() );
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            log.error( "Error finding user:"+user.id, e );
        }
        return userDto != null ? new UserVO( userDto ) : null;
    }

(...)

}
```

I developed and unit tested the classes using `@Singleton` (for simplicity), and everything works fine this way, but I get frequent errors like this, now that I have switched to `@SessionScoped` for production:

```
Guice provision errors:
1) Error in custom provider, org.apache.shiro.session.InvalidSessionException:
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
   HttpSession based implementations of the Shiro Session interface requires attribute keys to be String objects.  The HttpSession class does not support anything other than String keys.
```

Obviously, Guice seems to use some custom Key object to store the objects in the session, and the Shiro HttpSession implementation can't handle that. Strangely enough, though, this exception does not occur for all of the `@SessionScoped` classes, but certainly for more than one.

I have been searching the web like crazy, looking for an idea what I could do - some way to force Guice to use Strings for keys, some other way to make the HttpSession more compatible, anything - but I can't seem to find any helpful information. Also, judging from my search results for the error message, I seem to be the only person on the planet who even has this problem at all...

Is there any way to make this work? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: How do you initialize `Shiro`? Trough installing `ShiroModule`?

Comment: I installed `ShiroAopModule` and a custom one that extends `ShiroWebModule` and has everything you would otherwise put in a `shiro.ini`. That also binds `SessionScoped.class` to `ShiroSessionScope`. There is no separate Module for `UsersImpl` - the interface `Users` is annotated with `@ImplementedBy`.

Comment: The whole setup works fine if I use `@Singleton` instead of `@SessionScoped`: All the injections work, and the entire app runs without errors - except for the fact that it's limited to a single user, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this question is hard to answer, but i try to give you some options...

You error is from upfront checking... so, i assume your application did not even start, right? Then you are very likely **using Production stage or there is some binding eagerly** created and that object refers to another in `Session` scope, which is problem. So, now you should change all your `SessionScope` direct injection to Providers injection as in this example:

Could you change

```
@Inject
public UserService users;
```

to

```
@Inject
public Provider<UserService> userProvider; //and call userProvider.get() when you will need it?
```

Why so?

1. `SessionScoped` objects are **accessible only whitin `GuiceFilter.doFilter()`** so if you mixing scopes it could end up in some runtime exceptions. Especially, when you change `Stage` to `Production` or set some Singletons to eagerly loaded. You can learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638844/guice-and-wicket-using-sessionscoped-injections/19680341#19680341). It is good practice to use `Providers` when mixing `Scopes`
2. The problem could be that the `Subject` is bind only inside `ShiroFilter.doFilter()` [check my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326128/shiro-in-javaee6-application/18341742#18341742). Then, if you are outside let say `GuiceFilter` the could be no `Subject` bound at that time. Again, try to use `Providers`.

Hope, will help a little.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try providers. Though the exception occurs when I call the page - the app starts without problems.

Comment: After some extensive tryouts and banging my head on the keyboard, I think I may have found the root of the whole problem: It looks like it was caused by a stale dependency (I use ehcache 2.7.4 to store the sessions, and in one of my modules, ehcache-core was still at a much older version). Too tired to test the entire app right now, but fwiw: The non-provider version seems to work fine, at least for what I've seen since I updated the dependencies.  Thanks for helping, I'll have a definite answer tomorrow.

Comment: It turns out the original error is really gone, now that I have updated all the dependencies to the most recent version.  However, your advice regarding providers a) helped me get on the right track and b) incidentally fixed another problem I was struggling with.  I will therefore accept your answer, even if it didn't exactly solve the question. Thanks again for helping!